# rewrite map code without using map

Tags: perl

I am working on a perl script which calls VMware vSphere perl API. I was facing few problems and while googling, I found a solution which seems to work for me. However, one of the important piece of the code is written with `map`. Credit goes to the VMware community member who wrote it. Here is the code:

```
$datastore_map = map { $_->{'mo_ref'}->{'value'} => $_  } @{$datastore_views || [ ]};
```

I am not able to understand what above line is doing.

So, Could you help me to convert above line into a foreach loop or something similar. Believing in TMTOWTDI, there has to be another way to write same logic.

I tried to learn the `map` function a lot of times but it always bounces off my head. Hence I want to implement above logic without using the `map` function.

**EDIT:**

After reading the answers, I think the it should be `%datastore_map` and not `$datastore_map`. Because the next line of the code is `$datastore = $datastore_map->{$moref->{'value'}};`

It has to be a typo.

I will accept the answer when stacoverflow allows me to. Thanks for the quick repsonces. I spend almost an hour trying to understand it and failed at it.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Thanks @nickisfat, @choroba and @ikegami for the responses. All the answers are correct but I can accept only one. So I will go with the one which was posted first in the chronological order. Thanks again for the answers.

Comment: If that's the next line, your code should be `my $datastore_map = { map BLOCK LIST };`. Adjusting my node. (Kinda stupid to add that layer of indirection if you ask me.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
map BLOCK LIST
```

is very similar to

```
do {
   my @list;
   for (LIST) {
      push @list, do BLOCK;
   }
   @list
};
```

The code you posted makes no sense. Either the LHS of the assignment was actually a hash, or there's a set of curlies missing. Let's say your code is actually

```
my $datastore_map = {
    map { $_->{'mo_ref'}->{'value'} => $_ }
     @{ $datastore_views || [ ] }
};
```

Before we start, let's rewrite that to the following to make things a bit simpler.

```
my %datastore_map =
    map { $_->{'mo_ref'}->{'value'} => $_ }
     @{ $datastore_views || [ ] };

my $datastore_map = \%datastore_map;
```

So that means what you have is equivalent to

```
my %datastore_map = do {
   my @list;
   for (@{ $datastore_views || [ ] }) {
      push @list, do { $_->{'mo_ref'}->{'value'} => $_ };
   }
   @list
};      

my $datastore_map = \%datastore_map;
```

And we can simplify that to

```
my %datastore_map;
for (@{ $datastore_views || [ ] }) {
   $datastore_map{ $_->{'mo_ref'}->{'value'} } = $_;
}      

my $datastore_map = \%datastore_map;
```

or

```
my %datastore_map;
if ($datastore_views) {
   for (@$datastore_views) {
      $datastore_map{ $_->{'mo_ref'}->{'value'} } = $_;
   }
}      

my $datastore_map = \%datastore_map;
```

Comment: I agree that the LHS in my code is wrong. but considering the next line of code which is `$datastore = $datastore_map->{$moref->{'value'}};` I think the LHS should be `%$datastore_map` and not `%datastore_map`. huh!! this is confusing.

Comment: The `my $datastore_map; %$datastore_map = map BLOCK LIST;` you suggested is equivalent to the shorter `my $datastore_map = { map BLOCK LIST };` I used in my update. I don't like your version because it takes needlessly indirect route.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to assing the result to a scalar?

If not, just use the following:

```
my %datastore_map;
for my $view (@$datastore_views) {
    $datastore_map{$view->{mo_ref}{value}} = $view;
}
```

If yes, you want to get the number of views times 2. So, use simply

```
$datastore_map = 2 * @$datastore_views;
```

But, in such a case, the name of the variable is badly chosen.

Comment: If I do `print $datastore_map`, it prints a number, so Yes, The result is a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

$datastore_views is an array containing hashes, the code creates a hash of those hashes ($datastore_map) keyed on the contents of {'mo_ref'}->{'value'}.

In foreach:

```
foreach my $item( @$datastore_views ){
    $datastore_map->{ $item->{'mo_ref'}->{'value'} } = $item;
}
```

edit:

or at least thats what it would be doing if the original code was:

```
%$datastore_map = map { $_->{'mo_ref'}->{'value'} => $_  } @{$datastore_views || [ ]};
```